# Communication between mobile devices and desktop browser over local network

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I've built a simple javascript game and thought that it would be a nice idea to create a mobile app that acts as a "controller" for that game.

However, since the game require somewhat realtime reaction I thought that the mobile app will need to communicate with the game (browser) via local wifi, eliminating the need for a server and assuring low latency.

1) Is that possible in any way?

2) Suppose I wrap the game with Phonegap/Cordova and run it on an tablet device, is communicating between the two is possible? (mobile device <=> tablet)

Comment: Browsers don't readily support listening sockets, so I *think* you would have to write the "controller" as a full fledged mobile app, which would listen for polling requests from the game, and respond with the player's inputs. This is probably more trouble than it's worth, unless you're looking for a big project. Hope someone else has a more elegant solution.